# How to incrementally load data from hive to solr

Tags: solr, hive

I have a solr collection which stores per day sales record. Say on 01/Jan I sold 100 products and I load data from hive to solr. Next day I again sold 100 products.I want to load data from 101 to 200.However my hive contains 200 records so if I enter data I am getting 300 records. 100 from 1st day and 200 from second day(100(first day) + 100(second day)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to incrementally load data from hive to solr.
1. Either delete data from solr and insert full data again.
   Works well for small tables but for large table will take lot of time

2. Use where clause to insert data from hive such that there is no duplicate data.